# What are the most prefered languages for writing a login script? Why?

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell, login

I am in the process of building a new windows domain (migration from Novell) and need to write a login script to map network drives/printers.  In the past I have used vbscript mixed in with a little wmi as needed.  I am considering using Powershell and am wondering if this is a good choice or if there are even better options.  The network is small ~ 20 xp machines and 5-10 printers.

Comment: My investigations into powershell ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113664/installing-powershell-on-600-client-computers-recommended-settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still use vbscript, because that is what is available on older versions of windows still used on our network without adding additional software.  I frequently want my startup and login scripts to work on newly installed machines.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Group Policy Preferences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd314380.aspx), if you don't have any Win2K Pro.  No scripts and lots of options and filtering, including WMI like filtering only no scripting necessary.  It also has a lot of other features like pushing shortcuts/files/regkeys/printers etc.

I just finished (this past weekend) a migration from Novell to Microsoft.  It certainly eases my short term pain of no ZenWorks replacement(Buying LANDesk next quarter).

You should definitely take a look.